# C++ List Insert Iterator Outside Range

Tags: c++, list, class

First off, I'm new to c++ and list, so it might be obvious and I'm just not seeing it, sorry :(

I'm trying to create a list of files, and I'm hitting an error when I try to push the first file to the list. Debug Assertion Error message is "list insert iterator outside range".

In the header file, I have:

```
class ConfigDefFile
{
public:
    ConfigDefFile( const char * dir_path, const char * file_name );

private:
    ConfigDef * config;
    static char filePath[ MAX_PATH + 1 ];
};

typedef list<ConfigDefFile *> ConfigDefFileList;

ConfigDefFileList def_files;
```

My code for adding a file to the list is:

```
char * root_path = NULL;
ConfigDefFile * def_file;

root_path = GetDefDir(); //Gets the root directory for the file.

def_file = new ConfigDefFile( root_path, file );

def_files.push_back( def_file ); //error occurs here
```

Any ideas as to what I'm doing that would cause this?

Comment: Please use std::string instead of const char*

Comment: The larger application interacts with C code, so I prefer char * for consistency/readability...

Comment: consistency is sort of a good reason but a) std::string will save you a lot of trouble b) if you need the const char* just call the c_str() method.

Comment: My educated guess is, you managed to corrupt the heap somewhere in the code you haven't shown. list::push_back is an innocent bystander that just happened to step on the landmine planted elsewhere.

Comment: Instead of a list of pointers, use a `list<ConfigDefFile>`. The fewer pointers you use the quicker you will have a bug-free program,

Comment: If your reason not to use `std::string` is for consistency with legacy `char*`s, you probably do not know enough about memory management to justify not using `std::string`.

Comment: alright alright I'm convinced, I'll make the switch when I'm less pressed for time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are corrupting the heap as Igor suggested.  Likely in the implementation of

ConfigDefFile::ConfigDefFile( const char * dir_path, const char * file_name );